# Dungeon Keeper 2 Style Map, Vertex Compression

Tags: algorithm

So  working on an little project but thinking about making maps efficient.  I have a grid of numbers say

```
100110
011011
010110
```

If you've ever played dungeon keeper, the idea is a 0 is a flat dug out square, and 1 is a still standing square.
I want to take advantage of the grid layout and be able to minimise the number of vertexes used. So instead of using individuals cubes for an area like:

```
1111
1111
1111
```

I want to just use 8.
Any idea on the best approach to this? or even just knows the name of the type of algorithm i should use. Something that can do it quickly on the fly would be preferable so not to bottle neck rendering.

Comment: Do you actually have performance issues using the expanded map? If I understood correctly, you want to somehow compress your map, is that right?

Comment: Not sure if there will be an performance issues, it seems inefficient though as I'll be rendering faces that can't be seen.
Yeah, compress it before it has to be rendered, so the map itself exists as a 2d array, then vertexes are made from that (and updated when array is updated)

Comment: You could do something like checking if the face has a empty square next to it ie. `[1,1,1,0,1]` would render the right face of the 3rd block and the left face of the 5th block, possibly limit it by the viewport first to minimise the ones you have to calculate

Comment: I'm pretty sure this will not be a performance issue. Rendering faces over the others is something that is inevitable even in the most powerful game engines. And they do a LOT of clipping due to the huge number of triangles they draw. Since your input is a very simple 2D array, keeping it expanded is very unlikely to cause any performance issues. Trying to optimize it would be a waste of time.

Comment: Although I don't know this game, so I cannot judge perfectly. If you have many of these "square-shaped objects", you could keep them as a set of `<x, y, width, height>` values and render them into the array (or screen) on each frame (or event). This would make more sense if these objects could move or you could interact with them. Otherwise, the fact that you are drawing over the previous ones is still true and like I said, won't be a performance issue.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a 2D/isometric equivalent of Occlusion Culling (or [Hidden Surface Detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_surface_determination)), ofc correct me if im wrong

Comment: cool thank you for the advise, if it helps the 2d array could be quite big, say 10,000 by 10,000 and i'm using the panda 3d engine (which i think uses direct x)
Also planning on texturing and lighting things ect.
Thanks AbstractChaos i think i'll go with that, thats sounds like a good method.

Comment: +1 for dungeon keeper 2. Besides that, you need to find the outline of adjacent squares (or columns as they appear in the 3D view) and render only those. An alternative would be storing only the outline vectors and adding new ones as new holes get digged - that isn't that complicated as it sounds, there a only a few transformations to be considered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that this is probably not gonna be a performance issue, but you could represent your map in a compressed map by using a (slightly modified) unbalanced Quad-tree.

- Start by your map consisting only of 1's. You can store this as a box of size n*n in the root node of your tree.
- IF you want to dig out one of the boxes you recursively walk down the tree, splitting the n*n box (or whatever you find there) using the default quad tree rules (= split an n*n box into four n/2*n/2 boxes, etc.). At some point you'll arrive in a leaf of the tree that only contains the single box (the one you want to dig out) and you may change it from 1 to 0.
- Additionally, after the leaf has changed and your recursive calls return (= you walk back up the tree towards the root node), you can check neighboring boxes for whether they may be merged. (If you have two neighboring boxes that are both dug out, you can merge them).

Another technique that is sometimes used when indexing low-dimensional data like this is a space filling curve. One that has good average locality and is reversible is the Hilbert curve. Basically, you may enumerate your boxes (dug out ones and filled ones) along the space filling curve and then use simple run-length compression.

The tree-idea allows you to reduce the number of rendered geometry (you can rescale texture, etc. to emulate n*n boxes by a single larger box). The space filling curve probably will only save you some memory.